# how to hide webservice public webmethods

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

Does anybody know how to hide public web methods on .asmx page ? I don't want my client to view available web methods.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Comment: For real ? My goodness. How difficult is WCF ? I'm just worried about security. Is WCF more secured than ASMX ?

Comment: WCF is the replacement for ASMX. In simple scenarios, WCF is just as simple as ASMX. If is far more secure and has far more features than ASMX. Also, Microsoft has stopped fixing bugs in the ASMX code. Have you just started using ASMX? If so, may I ask why you thought ASMX was the right way to create web services?

Comment: No i have been using ASMX for quite some time. I will look for a decent book that talks about WCF. Many thanks.

Comment: Yea, `+1` for switching to WCF.  I switched [my site](http://www.kitchenpc.com) from ASMX to WCF a while back, and holy cow is it better.

Comment: Cool website, it makes me feel hungry. Do you know of any decent WCF books ?

Comment: Thanks!  Naw, I just kinda learned it from reading docs, blogs, tutorials, and posting StackOverflow questions..  I find books not really worth the money these days.  Oh, I did write [this blog post](http://blog.kitchenpc.com/2012/12/05/one-does-not-simply-switch-to-wcf/) on my switch to WCF though.  You might find it helpful.

Comment: Thanks Mike. I will have a look at this site.

Comment: @Mike how do you hide page extension(.aspx) on a website? Your site(http://www.kitchenpc.com/) doesn't show page extensions at all.

Comment: @chosenOneThabs - That's pretty easy, just make everything a directory with a default document!

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the *help* documentation (the HTML page generated when someone goes to the .asmx page without any parameters) by adding the following to your `web.config`:

```
<webServices>
     <protocols>
       <remove name="Documentation" />
     </protocols>
</webServices>
```

[More Info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2tyf2t8t.aspx)

Comment: I've added these lines in the web config. Now i get 'Unrecognized configuration section webServices' error message. I've added these lines under <system.web> and just above <compilation debug="true" >

Comment: Hmm, it's working for me.  You might have to add the assembly reference: `<add assembly="System.Web.Services, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />`

Comment: I'm using framework 3.5. Visual Studio doesn't allowed me to create a web service application in framework 4.0. If i choose new project and choose framework 4.0 then web service application option disappears. It only appears if i choose framework 3.5. Do you know why is this ? If i add your assembly line the site bombs. It complains about framework 4.0

Comment: Sorry i managed to change the framework under project properties. But i still get 'Unrecognized configuration section webServices'  error message.

Comment: Hmm, maybe dig through [this article](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/121207-1.aspx) - There's something messed up with your `web.config` I'm pretty sure!

Comment: I will look at this article. I will let you know as soon as i come right. Thanks Mike.